# vscode how to use: from png import *

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, modulenotfounderror

Im trying to use this command in visual studio code: `from png import *`

but if I run my code I get this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'png'`
also if I try `conda activate base` in my terminal I get this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k28Uo.png)

if anyone knows how to fix this please tell me

Comment: have you tried what the error messages says, the point of printing an error message is notifying that something is wrong and what you might so to fix it

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7980#issuecomment-441358406

Answer (score 0):

May be library is not correctly installed or you are using the wrong environment to execute your python script.

Try restarting your PowerShell and running the command *conda init*. This can help as the message says.

Answer (score 0):

Try the command in the command prompt(cmd.exe) and not powershell. Also try running this `conda init powershell` to get conda working in powershell.

Also to install the png module use `pip install pypng` when the base environment is active.